# No such file or directory - when running git add

Tags: git, github

I'm going to upload my code to the github repository and execute the `git add .` command. I get this error and I do not know what to do in this case.

```
fatal: Unable to create '/Documents/GitHub/repo/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked file system permissions? Do you have write privileges to /Documents/GitHub/repo/.git? I am assuming you preceded this command with `git init`.

Answer (score 1):

1. remove the current file and it should work

   ```
   rm -f ./.git/index.lock
   ```
2. Check to see if you have other git operation running in the background

Answer (score 1):

Check the option in windows security centre for Allow and app through Controlled Folder Access and add git.exe to the allowed list of apps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder somewhere else and do some git commands there, for some reason your folder is protected.