# git init command shows "no such file or directory"

Tags: git

I am trying to upload a project. I follow github instructions but when I initialize a repository using GitBash using `$git init` command it shows `no such file or directory` error.

Comment: Possibly duplicate [answer]
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53713300/no-such-file-or-directory-when-running-git-add

Comment: This answer didn't clear where exactly is the issue

Comment: What does the current directory your're in looks like and how did you create it ?  What is the exact command your are typing ? What is the complete output you're getting ? Please do not add those info in comment, edit your answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure, that specific folder is not virus protected via windows defender's ransomware protection.

Comment: God should help someone if he/she accidentally activated Windows Ransomeware Protection! All the normal application are unable to create or edit files, with strange error messages, and without any explicit notice.

Comment: Nowadays you get a notification from Ransomware Protection, you click it, click the latest one, Actions > Allow on device.

Answer (score 2):

The [GitHub instructions](https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line) include:

> Initialize the local directory as a Git repository.
>
> ```
> $ git init
> ```

So make sure to cd first to the root folder of your local sources, and check:

- there is no `.git` subfolder
- you have the right to write (create new files) in that root folder